"from my parents' house." VS "up from parents' house."
A native English speaker said this when moving around London:

Well guys, It's Saturday. We've arrived in London. We got the train up from my parents house.

"...to get the train up..." caught my attention. At first, I thought "to get up the train"  seemed like a phrasal verb like "to get on the train", but then you wouldn't say "to get the train up" or "to get the train on."
So I thought maybe the "up" is not connected to "get" but to the the next word "from". So, it becomes "get the train up from my parents' house."
But then I wonder why "up from" instead of "from"?

British people often say they are going 'up' to London from somewhere outside the city, or if they are travelling north. The opposite (from London to somewhere else, or from north to south) can be 'down'. Maybe after the weekend they will be going back down to the parents' house.

get the train = take the train, up from wherever, down from wherever. The parse is: get the train//up from x or down from x and that's the same across varieties of English.

@MichaelHarvey Many moons ago, I gave that exact description and I was told in no uncertain terms - which I believe were mistaken - that the north/south thing was not accurate. Unbelievable. The person telling me that said you can say: I went up to London, even if you are north of the city. Look: "(The "down for south" thing happens as well, so the two factors interfere - living in the north of England, I would be about as likely to refer to London as "up" as I would "down")."
SamBC
CommentedMar 2, 2019 at 21:29

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/198830/the-meaning-of-up-in-the-phrase-up-in-london/198838#198838 Check out all the downvotes. Why don't you pop over there and put them straight on this? :)

@Lambie - I know they say 'two Jews, three opinions', but believe me, when it comes to stuff like this, it applies to the Brits too. It's probably true that while many do, not everyone says 'down to London' if they live 'up north', (where it's grim, according to the JAMS), and up/down (London/country) but anyone saying it's wildly wrong is talking out of their southern extremity.

@MichaelHarvey Of course. I agree with your first comment and am saying that a fellow countryman of yours says that is not true. Yes, out of their derrière. These downvotes bother me when they are patently untrue.

got complicates the sentence for me because "got the train up"  is not idiomatic in American English. We'd say "took the train up." If we use "get the train" we mean "to not miss the train or to not fail to board it for some other reason"  i.e.  "to be able to take the train".  We can't get the train from this platform. Because of work on the rails, we need to board from the other side of the track.

@TimR That is wrong. First, because it is not "got the train up". It's: got the train + up from my parent's house (i.e. town). And two, in American English get (take)  a type of transportation (bus, train, plane, ferry) is very common. Finally, we often say things like: I got the train down from Saratoga to New York. OR He got the train up from New York to Saratoga.  Perfectly idiomatic. Those are prepositional phrases in all the cases I'm pointing out.

@Lambie   In AmE it would be idiomatic to say "I took the train up|down from somewhere" and I can cite plenty of attestations of that.  "got the train down" is used in BrE but can you show some attestations supporting your claim that "got the train down|up" is perfectly idiomatic in AmE?  I dispute that claim.

"We got the train to Miami whilst here on vacation in Orlando", "We got the train to London", "We got the train to Bath".    Just show me the names of a few American cities in an utterance made by a native speaker of AmE and I will concede the point, even though I've never ever heard an American use the locution "got the train" synonymously with "took the train".

@TimR I got a train down, not the bus. Same as took.

@Lambie  You shouldn't just jump in with a peremptory "That is wrong" if you're not ready to back it up with evidence. Simply reiterating your point doesn't make it so.  "took a train down" you don't dispute, so it's up to you to show some attestations of AmE "got the train down".

@TimR This is wrong: "got complicates the sentence for me because "got the train up" is not idiomatic in American English." And I said why. I gave three reasons. Do you just like using terms like peremptory?? This is idiomatic: How did you get here? Answer: We got the train up. It may be more UK than NA but it can be used and it is idiomatic. I don't attest a lot of things because they are internalized. And the parse is really: Get the train/up from my parents. Though we can say just: we got or took the train up.

"Reasons" are not attestations.

Sample: Well guys, It's Saturday. We've arrived in London. We got the train// up from my parents house//.
London could be replaced by the name of any city or place south or north or east or west of another.

get the train = take the train = travel by train
get on the train = to board the train
up from or down from [a place]
to get the/a train up or down [from a place]

up from or down from a place is a prepositional phrase.
Of course, one can choose not to say up or down and just say from a place. (We got on the train from London.) The up or down merely positions the speaker as being north of or south of the place where they departed from.

They flew the plane up from South Carolina. i.e. towards the north, away from the place of departure.


My pal from Tampa said that 'the nuts roll down to Florida'. He also tried to annoy some people in Vancouver by raising a glass and drinking a toast to 'America's hat', but they laughed and bought him another beer. So this north/south up/down thing is widely ingrained at least among people who aren't 'map-blind' (they do exist). Plus the Florida thing invokes gravity.

@MichaelHarvey Sure, they roll down from the northern states. Especially in winter. They are called snowbirds.

LIke my cousin in London, Ontario.

@MichaelHarvey I wonder how he'd react to the three downvotes I got.

Railway terminology
Or, railroad terminology, for the North Americans.
Railways have an “up” direction and a “down” direction. Trains on the up line travel up from the up platform, trains on the down line travel down from the down platform. The up direction is the direction in which the chainage decreases towards zero. The numbers that you see on the stanchion posts are the chainage, although I believe they measure it in metres rather than chains these days, even in England, however, “meterage” never really caught on.
Since the zero point is usually measured from the major terminus end, up is usually towards the most major terminus. In the UK, that’s usually London, although Birmingham, Liverpool, Manchester, etc. are probably also up. I don’t know the British rail network enough to be definitive but local networks would have their own zero point and as they merged there will be a point where up and down ‘flip’. For example, in New South Wales, chainage flips at Morriset as both Sydney and Newcastle have their own local zeros, chainage also flips at the state border.
So, in the 19th century when railways were the new and exciting technology, people knew far more of the engineer’s jargon than they do today. They would therefore know they caught the up train on the up line from the up platform to get to London, so, they naturally spoke of going “up to London” or “down to the country”.
The expression lingers although most people no longer know the reason.

This is not rail terminology at all. get [or take] a method of transportation up or down from or to x is common in English. So, for conversational purposes, this really doesn't help. We got [took] a plane down from New York yesterday. up/down and even across sometimes.

@Lambie sure, that’s the modern usage, but railways are the origin of the expression

Could be sailing, which is obviously a much older method of transportation: We sailed down/up the coast.

The key consideration is to notice that the location at which they have arrived is London in particular. In British English it is quite common to speak of going (or coming) up to London.
So the up doesn’t bind to the from my parents’ house but rather to the to London.
